# Python 3.x error with methods asking for input error is TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, methods, user-input

I'm attempting utilizing TeamTreehouse learning subscription & this Starting Out With Programming Logic And Design (3rd Ed) book to attempt learning programming & Python. Please don't shoot to kill me I'm learning.

**Goal:** I'm attempting to set a Pet class with 3  fields/attributes/properties. The class will have 2 methods, set & get, for each field/attribute/property. I'm trying to figure out how to get each method (which is still a function at it's roots) to ask user's for input to then set the internal attributes to the input values.

**Researching & Troubleshooting:** I can get it to run error free when I don't ask users to input data as part of class methods. http://repl.it/oIr/3

I've referred to a "cheat sheet" for what OOP could look like. http://www.newthinktank.com/2014/11/python-programming/

Here is a doc that I flipped through that appears to be a 2.x python version reference on OOP though it didn't do much for relieving or causing a change on my headache.

***I found this document right before posting which is starting to make sense of my cloudy head. Likely I need to clean/scrub all my passing by value/reference coding then rewrite?
[How to get user input within a Method (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041914/how-to-get-user-input-within-a-method-python)***

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 43, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

**CODE:**
http://repl.it/oIr/5

```
# Create class for Pet

class Pet:
    __name = ""
    __species = ""
    __age = ""

    # Object constructor
    def __init__():
        self.__name = name
        self.__species = species
        self.__age = age

    #Methods    
    def setName(self):
        self.__name =input("What is your pet's name?\n")

    def setSpecies(self, species):
        self.__species=input("What type of pet is it?\n")

    def setAge(self, age):
        self.__age=input("How old is your pet?\n")

    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getSpecies(self):
        return self.__species

    def getAge(self):
        return self.__age

    def get_type(self):
        print("Pet")

    def toString(self):
        return"{} is a {} and is {} years old".format(self.__name,self.__species,self.__age)

#name=input("What is your pet's name?\n")
#species=input("What type of pet is it?\n")
#age=input("How old is your pet?\n")

myPet=Pet()
myPet.setName()

#myPet=Pet(name,species,age)
print(myPet.toString())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods in Python take a `self` argument. Your `__init__` method doesn't:

```
def __init__():
```

but Python is still trying to supply one:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Add the `self` argument:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Your next problem is that your `__init__` method expects the variables `name`, `species` and `age` to be available, but you never set those:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__name = name
    self.__species = species
    self.__age = age
```

Perhaps you meant to make those method arguments:

```
def __init__(self, name, species, age):
    self.__name = name
    self.__species = species
    self.__age = age
```

which means you can only create a new `Pet()` instance by including those values:

```
name = input("What is your pet's name?\n")
species = input("What type of pet is it?\n")
age = input("How old is your pet?\n")

myPet = Pet(name, species, age)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Martijn I somehow got all turned around!